# How to convert raster negetive pixel value to positive

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator

I was working on ground water Level. I used raster math minus function  and the Output raster  grid data contains negetive cell values. ma resulting raster contains values ranges from High : 0,187477 to Low : -1,14927. But I do not want any negetive values.I just need to alter the negetive sign to positive vales.How can I do that using arcgis10.2

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details of the steps that you have performed, leading up to where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the abs function in raster calculator

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works but I have found a Little Problem with the Pixel values. ´The Output raster has Little different Pixel value than the original. The outraster Pixel values ranges from High:1.14927 and low:0.0379639. I tried in the Environment to use compression None. but it did not work: -) Do you have any idea how it works !!

Comment: I guess the pixel values are different because of the conversion from negative to positive so your previous low value of -1.14927 is now a high of 1.14927. Perhaps instead of removing the negatives you could add a number to the pixel values? This would allow you to change the negatives to positives and keep the difference between your high value and low value